# Copy rows to sheet2 in value in range is met

Tags: vba, excel

I am complete newbee when it comes to Excel VBA

I have a task to copy rows from sheet1 to sheet 2 if certain criteria is met.

In sheet1 there are values in columns JY ending in column MV
I would like if you can help me to write a macro to copy all rows to sheet2 containing values that are less than 1.
it is possible that one row can have multiple <1 values.

For example: Row 16 can have under column jY 0.9  and under MA 0.5

Best outcome will be to see only columns A,B,C,D and column with values less than 1 in sheet 2, but if that is not possible copying entire row would be fine.

So far I have found a code which is copying values that are exactly 1

Here is code that I would like to be changed:

```
    Sub SearchForNumber1()
Dim LSearchRow As Integer
Dim LCopyToRow As Integer
On Error GoTo Err_Execute
'Start search in row 1
LSearchRow = 1
'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
LCopyToRow = 2
While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0
'If value in column E = "Mail Box", copy entire row to Sheet2
If Range("B" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "1" Then
'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
Selection.Copy
'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
'Move counter to next row
LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1
'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
End If
LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1
Wend
'Position on cell A3
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A3").Select
MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."
Exit Sub
Err_Execute:
MsgBox "An error occurred."
End Sub
```

Comment: `found a code which is copying values that are exactly 1` So modify it for `<1`. Take the value, multiply by 1 then test if less than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this will help,

```
Sub moveData()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim iniCol As Range
    Dim i
    Dim c
    Dim myIndex
    Dim cellVal
    Dim totalCols
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet

    Set sht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set rng = Range("K1:M32")
    Set iniCol = Range("K1:K32")
    totalCols = rng.Columns.Count 'Count the total of columns in the selectec range
    myIndex = 0 'ini the index for rows in sheet2

    For Each i In iniCol
        For c = 1 To totalCols
            cellVal = i.Offset(0, c - 1).Value
            If cellVal < 1 Then
                myIndex = myIndex + 1
                Range(Cells(i.Row, 1), Cells(i.Row, 3)).Copy 
                'Copy range from A to C
                sht2.Activate
                Range(Cells(myIndex, 1), Cells(myIndex, 3)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                'Paste range equal to copy range.
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                sht1.Activate
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c
    Next i
End Sub
```

In columns A, B, C and K, L, M

```
HMG BNA ALI                             -2  6   4
HCM INH KJA                             6   5   2
DDN EHJ AKK                             1   -7  -6
OLG BMG AJC                             -7  1   0
CGK PEA EFB                             6   5   2
BGO CGI EOO                             8   -9  -2
NHB CGP IEJ                             -2  3   -8
PNK JBN HKJ                             6   5   2
ABC JIG NHB                             8   8   -10
BBO EIL NDH                             -1  10  -7
GJE PNK LNL                             2   8   10
GMF HIF EFP                             6   5   2
AIB EJP NDL                             -6  -5  8
IKM IIA GDL                             6   5   0
PCE KJA HPJ                             6   5   2
FFE KFM CPB                             -5  -1  -10
MHO IJL FCL                             6   5   2
EPI PPF IOE                             -5  2   -5
ANO PAO HHG                             6   5   2
MGL GII PEB                             -3  8   2
PJK OKI GME                             -3  4   10
AEP NMN JML                             6   5   2
ANE KBK NGJ                             -10 -7  -4
JLJ IIH OLG                             6   5   2
PLH HBK PIK                             -9  6   -3
ICC MEB LKO                             6   5   2
MBH OGA JJA                             4   9   0
IAN HBK ANJ                             6   5   2
FNP FPE KLG                             2   2   8
LAI ALE HHP                             6   5   2
NLG IFG MDB                             -10 -8  0
ICE OHG BFH                             9   -8  0
```

Result:

Just import this rows, only from A to C (if you want also the values just increase the column of the copy range)

```
HMG BNA ALI
DDN EHJ AKK
OLG BMG AJC
BGO CGI EOO
NHB CGP IEJ
ABC JIG NHB
BBO EIL NDH
AIB EJP NDL
IKM IIA GDL
FFE KFM CPB
EPI PPF IOE
MGL GII PEB
PJK OKI GME
ANE KBK NGJ
PLH HBK PIK
MBH OGA JJA
NLG IFG MDB
ICE OHG BFH
```

An image worth a thousand words
[image: an image worth a thousand words]

**Edit #1**

Here is the code as you ask in comments:

```
Sub moveData()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim iniCol As Range
    Dim i
    Dim c
    Dim myIndex
    Dim cellVal
    Dim totalCols
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet

    Dim ABC 'var to store data from Cols A,B,C in Sheet1
    Dim KLM 'var to store data from Cols K,L,M in Sheet1

    Set sht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set rng = Range("K1:M32")
    Set iniCol = Range("K1:K32")
    totalCols = rng.Columns.Count 'Count the total of columns in the selectec range
    myIndex = 0 'ini the index for rows in sheet2

    For Each i In iniCol
        For c = 1 To totalCols
            cellVal = i.Offset(0, c - 1).Value
            If cellVal < 1 Then
                myIndex = myIndex + 1
                'Now anything is copied, instead is stored inside this two vars, cols A, B, C and K, L, M as well
                ABC = Range(Cells(i.Row, 1), Cells(i.Row, 3))
                KLM = Range(Cells(i.Row, 11), Cells(i.Row, 13))
                '
                sht2.Activate
                Range(Cells(myIndex, 1), Cells(myIndex, 3)).Value = ABC
                Range(Cells(myIndex, 6), Cells(myIndex, 8)).Value = KLM 
                'and put it back in sheet2 in cols 1=A to 3=C and 6=F to 8=H
                '
                'Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Not used anymore.
                sht1.Activate
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Edit#2**

Go over the values, and if any value is <1 then put the value ONLY in column F, in one row, the next value in another cell.

```
Sub moveData()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim iniCol As Range
    Dim i
    Dim v
    Dim x
    Dim myIndex
    Dim cellVal
    Dim totalCols
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet

    Dim ABC() 'var to store data from Cols A,B,C in Sheet1
    Dim KLM As Range 'var to store data from Cols K,L,M in Sheet1

    Set sht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set rng = Range("K1:M32")
    Set iniCol = Range("K1:K32")
    totalCols = rng.Columns.Count 'Count the total of columns in the selectec range
    myIndex = 0 'ini the index for rows in sheet2

    For Each i In iniCol
    x = -1
        ABC = Range(Cells(i.Row, 1), Cells(i.Row, 3))
        Set KLM = Range(Cells(i.Row, 11), Cells(i.Row, 13))
        'Copy range from A to C

        sht2.Activate

        myIndex = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1)) + 1
        For Each v In KLM
            If v.Value < 1 Then
                x = x + 1
                Range(Cells(myIndex + x, 6), Cells(myIndex + x, 6)).Value = v.Value
                Range(Cells(myIndex + x, 1), Cells(myIndex + x, 3)).Value = ABC
            End If
        Next v
        'Paste range equal to copy range.
        'Application.CutCopyMode = False
        sht1.Activate
    Next i
End Sub
```

This is my result:

```
HMG BNA ALI         -2
DDN EHJ AKK         -7
DDN EHJ AKK         -6
OLG BMG AJC         -7
OLG BMG AJC         0
BGO CGI EOO         -9
BGO CGI EOO         -2
NHB CGP IEJ         -2
NHB CGP IEJ         -8
ABC JIG NHB         -10
BBO EIL NDH         -1
BBO EIL NDH         -7
AIB EJP NDL         -6
AIB EJP NDL         -5
IKM IIA GDL         0
FFE KFM CPB         -5
FFE KFM CPB         -1
FFE KFM CPB         -10
EPI PPF IOE         -5
EPI PPF IOE         -5
MGL GII PEB         -3
PJK OKI GME         -3
ANE KBK NGJ         -10
ANE KBK NGJ         -7
ANE KBK NGJ         -4
PLH HBK PIK         -9
PLH HBK PIK         -3
MBH OGA JJA         0
NLG IFG MDB         -10
NLG IFG MDB         -8
NLG IFG MDB         0
ICE OHG BFH         -8
ICE OHG BFH         0
```

Comment: This works ElbertV, is it possible for you to change the code so it copies the values also, and to show values from K,L,M from sheet1 in your example to the column F in sheet2?

Take into consideration that like in your example Line 16 have multiple values under 1 so in sheet2 we need new row for every value. Thank You really for your time and help

Comment: Check my Edit#1 and see if is ok. But I don't get the whole idea about a new row for each value. You say, if all the 3 values are under 1, you need a new row for each value, and then, for the line 16, (-5,-1,-10) you need two new rows??? It is that way??? In case it is, what values will be on each row? The same three values on the new rows, or one value in each row? After that some questions come to my mind... But please gimme all the detail, to help you in the correct way.

Comment: I just run it and this is almost perfect. Only issue is that now all values are copied to the sheet2 and not just <1. How to solve this?
And regarding your question- If in Sheet1 Line 16 has -5,-1 and -10 i would like to have 3 new rows in sheet 2
Example
Sheet 2
Line 16 Column A,B,C and in column F -5
Line 17 Column A B C and in column F -1
Line 18 Column A B C and in column F -10
If You could write that all values found goes to column F in sheet2 that would be perfection and a huuge time-saver.

Comment: I ran the code again and for me, take only the rows (from sheet1) that contains a value (any of the three values,no matter wich one) <1 and move it (only that rows) to sheet2. In sheet1 I have 32 lines, and as a result in sheet2 I get just 18 lines, and in that lines, every rows, has at least one value under 1. Please re-check your code, and tell me if everything is as I reply to you.

Comment: And now, about adding the new lines... I'm clear, if the three values are unde 1, you want every value (<1) in a new row, and each value (<1) in the column F, that is ok for me... But, what if not all the values are <1, may be lik this {-9,6,-3} or like this {9-8,0} or this way {-2,6,4}.

Comment: Yes, you are correct - only values <1 should go into F column.
In Your example (-9,6,-3) only -9 and -3 should go into sheet2.
In second example only -8 should go into sheet2, third example only -2.
Not entire row should be copied into sheet2 just names(columns A,B,C) and just value that is <1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100189/discussion-between-elbertv-and-marko-m).

Answer (score 2):

Collecting the values into a variant array will make quick work of running through them looking for valid values to bring over to Sheet2.

```
Sub copy_multi_less_than_one()
    Dim rw As Long, cl As Long
    Dim bCOPY As Boolean, v As Long, vVALs As Variant

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            For rw = 2 To .Rows.Count
                vVALs = .Cells(rw, 1).Resize(1, 360).Value2
                bCOPY = False
                For v = 5 To UBound(vVALs, 2)
                    If v < 285 Then
                        vVALs(1, v) = vbNullString
                    ElseIf application.sum(vVALs(1, v)) >= 1 Then
                        vVALs(1, v) = vbNullString
                    Else
                        bCOPY = True
                    End If
                Next v
                If bCOPY Then
                    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
                        .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, UBound(vVALs, 2)) = vVALs
                    End With
                End If
            Next rw
            'optionally delete the columns from E to JX
            'Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns("E:JX").EntireColumn.Delete
        End With
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: @ Jeeped, when i tried to run your code I get an error : ``Run  time error 13 Type mismatch`` Can you please explain how to fix this? 
@ ElbertV, this looks exactly like what I want but I am getting this error: error 9, subscript out of range.

Comment: It would seem that you either have errors,  non-numeric text or text-that-looks-like-a-number within the values. None of these can be compared to a number (e.g. <1). I could easily write a numeric check in but that will not solve bad data that may be thrown out when it should be accepted. What line is giving you this error message? I suspect `If vVALs(1, v) >= 1 Or v < 285 Then` but I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, line 13.
In sheet1 columns A,B,C,D have letters.
Columns from E to JX have numbers(cell are drop down lists, maybe this is important to mention)
And third section of sheet1 from JY to MV have numbers - because third section are results(from E-JX) most of them have numeric values but some have #DIV/0!
So range to look for values under 1 should be just JY:MV
Thank You so much for helping me

Comment: OK I've broken out the two conditions within that section and added a safety for non-numeric values. Hard to guess what else could be wrong without seeing data.

Comment: Yes, this is better but now In line 9 error : Subscript out of range.

Comment: Here are print screen`s of how xlsx file looks like, if you need any additional info please ask.
http://postimg.org/image/f6klood21/
http://postimg.org/image/c0zzyguft/

[url=http://postimg.org/image/c0zzyguft/][img]http://s28.postimg.org/c0zzyguft/image.png[/img][/url]

Comment: uh... yeah... I'll get right on that as soon as I type out several test rows worth of 360 columns of data.